# ttk creating and using a custom theme

Tags: tkinter, themes, python-3.3, ttk

I am trying to incorporate a customizable theme choice in my program. I have been referring to this guide: http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-themes.html, but I am lost.

Here is a sample code I have been using to try to figure this out. I created a new theme, "Shadow," correctly, but the next part I'm struggling with. Let's just keep it simple and say within the "Shadow" theme I would like to change the frame background to black, the button background to navy and the button foreground to white.

How would I do this?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class Main:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.main_button = ttk.Button(self.master, text = 'New', command = self.new_window)
        self.main_button.grid()

    def new_window(self):
        pop_up = Top(self.master)

class Top:
    def __init__(self, master):
        pop_up = self.pop_up = Toplevel(master)
        self.pop_up_frame = ttk.Frame(pop_up, height = 100, width = 100)
        self.pop_up_frame.grid(sticky = E+W+S+N)
        self.s = ttk.Style()
        self.s.theme_create('shadow', parent = 'default')

        print(self.s.theme_names())

        self.c1_button = ttk.Button(pop_up, text = 'Default', command = self.get_default)
        self.c2_button = ttk.Button(pop_up, text = 'Shadow', command = self.get_shadow)

        self.c1_button.grid()
        self.c2_button.grid()    

    def get_default(self):
        self.s.theme_use('default')

    def get_shadow(self):
        self.s.theme_use('shadow')


root = Tk()

app = Main(root)

root.mainloop()
```

As always, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

I was making this far too difficult.

Here was the solution for anybody else trying to figure this out:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class Main:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.main_button = ttk.Button(self.master, text = 'New', command = self.new_window)
        self.main_button.grid()

    def new_window(self):
        pop_up = Top(self.master)

class Top:
    def __init__(self, master):
        pop_up = self.pop_up = Toplevel(master)
        self.pop_up_frame = ttk.Frame(pop_up, height = 100, width = 100)
        self.pop_up_frame.grid(sticky = E+W+S+N)
        self.s = ttk.Style()
        self.s.theme_create('shadow', parent = 'default')

        print(self.s.theme_names())

        self.c1_button = ttk.Button(pop_up, text = 'Default', command = self.get_default)
        self.c2_button = ttk.Button(pop_up, text = 'Vista', command = self.get_shadow)

        self.c1_button.grid()
        self.c2_button.grid()

    def get_default(self):
        self.s.theme_use('default')

    def get_shadow(self):
        self.s.theme_use('vista')
        self.s.configure('TButton', foreground = 'white', background = 'blue')
        self.s.configure('TFrame', background = 'black')



root = Tk()

app = Main(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3):

To simplify [Gregory6106's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35443360/3357935), you can modify your current theme theme using `.configure()`.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class MainPage(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.main_label = ttk.Label(self, text="Pointless Text")
        self.main_button = ttk.Button(self, text="Pointless Button")
        self.main_label.pack(padx=5, pady=5)
        self.main_button.pack(padx=5, pady=5)

        # Configure custom theme
        self.s = ttk.Style()
        self.s.configure('TLabel', foreground='red', background='grey')
        self.s.configure('TButton', foreground='white', background='blue')
        self.s.configure('TFrame', background='black')


root = Tk()
app_frame = MainPage(root)
app_frame.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

[image: Example of a themed page in tkinter.ttk]

**Note**: This solution works by configuring the pre-existing theme rather than creating a new one. As a result, this may not work if you plan on swapping back to the original theme during runtime.